# How to print certain fields in a column if one of the fields is less than a certain value?

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, field

I have a .txt file in that contains data about 100 colleges in the format

```
{COLLEGE NAME} {CITY, STATE} {RANK} {TUITION} {IN STATE TUITION} {ENROLLMENT}
```

For example here are two lines

```
YeshivaUniversity "New York, NY" 66 "$40,670 "  "2,744" 
FordhamUniversity "New York, NY" 60 "$47,317 "  "8,855"
```

There are 98 more lines and the output should return all the colleges with tuition less than $30000?

Assuming that the field separator is space, how could I print the `{COLLEGE NAME} {CITY, STATE} {TUITION}` of colleges with `{TUITION}` less than `$30,000`? Is it possible to do with `awk` or `sort`?

I have tried some combinations of `awk` and the operators `<=`, but I get an error every time. For example

```
$ awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $4<=30000}' data1a.txt
```

gives me a syntax error.

Comment: I just realized that, but theoretically how would you do it if that wasn't a problem?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk, since it's got `FPAT`:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^ ]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
    tuition=$4                    # separate 4th column for cleaning
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",tuition)     # clean non-digits off
    if(tuition<30000)             # compare
        print                     # and output
}'
```

Output for sample data:

(Next time, please post such sample that it has positive and negative cases.)

Also, it was mentioned in the comments: *Delimited by single space and you have a space in name of University*. That wasn't the case anymore when I saw your question but that could be tackled by counting the fields from the end, ie. `$4` would be `$(NF-1)`.